# Integral leading to inverse trigo function

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int \frac{3}{2+3x^2} dx $$

I try to follow this formula -

$$ \int \frac{1}{a^2 + x^2} dx = \frac{1}{a} \tan^{-1} \frac{x}{a} + C $$

My attempt -

$\int \frac{3}{2+3x^2} dx = \int \frac{3}{(\sqrt{2})^2) + (\sqrt{3x})^2} $

Let $u = \sqrt{3x} $

$ dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} du $

$\int \frac{3}{(\sqrt{2})^2) + (u^2)} (\frac{1}{\sqrt {3}} du )$

I'm not sure how to carry on from here ...

Comment: You can take the constant $\sqrt{3}$ out if the integral and then use $a=\sqrt{2}$ and $x=u$.

Comment: $$\frac3{2+3x^2}=\frac1{2/3+x^2}$$ so it looks like you can apply the formula with $a=\sqrt{2/3}$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I got $\frac{2}{3} \int \frac{1}{1+u^2} (\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}} du $ so why is a $\sqrt{2/3}$ and not $\sqrt{3/2} $ ?

Comment: You have $u$ as the variable. I have $x$. They have a different scale, and that shows.

Answer (score 1):

$\int \frac{3}{2+3x^2} dx=\frac{3}{2}\int \frac{1}{1+(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}x)^2} dx$.

Can you proceed ?

Comment: From this , I can't still get how I will get the answer - $ \sqrt{3/2} \tan^{-1} \sqrt{3/2}x + C $

Comment: Substitution $t=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}x$

Comment: I got $\frac{3}{2} \int{ \frac{1}{1+u^2}} (\frac{1}{\sqrt{3/2}}) du  .$ How do I get rid of $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3/2}})$  from it , isn't a = 1 ? but from the formula - $1/a = \sqrt{3/2} $ sorry as I'm still very confused .

Answer (score 1):

We have 
$$
\begin{align*}
\int \frac{3}{2+3x^2} dx 
&= \int \frac{1}{\frac{2}{3}+x^2} dx  \hspace{12mm}\mbox{ divide top and bottom by $3$}\\ 
&= \int \frac{1}{\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\right)^2 +x^2} dx  \\ 
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}} \tan^{-1}\left( \frac{x}{\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}} \right)  + C \\ 
&= \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} \tan^{-1} \left(\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\: x  \right) + C. \\  
\end{align*}
$$